# How to log to an external file from SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a 3rd party software which calls a stored procedure in my SQL Server to insert log entries. I would rather have the log entries write directly to a txt file instead of being in a SQL Server table.

I have tried collecting the entries in a `##temptable` and using BCP to write them out but ran into an issue. The 3rd party software wraps all calls to the stored procedure in a transaction which causes BCP to hang during exports.

I thought about using a `##temptable` and having a SQL Server Agent job dump it on a regular interval but the transactions can be long running and I'm not sure how to make sure I can write entries to the text files without duplicate or missing rows depending on transaction lengths.

Is there a good way to write from a stored procedure into a file? If so, is there a way to batch the writes over multiple calls of the stored procedure?

Comment: possible to add another flag in the log entry table ? clear it after SQLAgent dump it to disk. If you can't touch that table, then use insert trigger to duplicate the entry to another table and do it there

Comment: Creative approach! I'm worried it might cause some excessive locking to run the update transaction while potentially many long-running insert transactions are running from the 3rd party software.  But there is definitely something in this suggestion! Thanks.

Comment: then maybe the new table is worh considering. It will not affect existing log entry table

Answer (score 1):

To access resources being out of SQL Server control from TSQL batch you can use a CLR Stored Procedure. With it you can write some .NET code to do anything you want with for example files or network connection. Then you have to prepare a DLL assembly and connect it with SQL Server. Here you are an example from MSDN how to create a procedure from external assembly:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyFirstUdp FROM 'C:\Programming\MyFirstUdp.dll';
CREATE PROCEDURE HelloWorld
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyFirstUdp.StoredProcedures.HelloWorld;
EXEC HelloWorld;
```

More information about CLR Stored Procedures (and presented example) you can find on https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms131094(v=sql.110).aspx